# Java SOAP web service over SSL with basic authentication, connection refused

Tags: java, soap, ssl, https

I am trying to send a SOAP request over SSL with my own little Java client and it fails with "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused". The same request sent with SOAPUI does not fail, I get a valid response from the server.

This is the code I am trying to run:

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

```
    System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");
    SSLUtilities.trustAllHttpsCertificates();


   URL wsdlURL = new URL(MY_WSDL_LOCATION);

   QName serviceName = new QName(MY_QNAME, NAME_OF_SERVICE);

   Service service = Service.create(wsdlURL, serviceName);

   Order myOrder  = service.getPort(Order.class);

   BindingProvider portBP = (BindingProvider) myOrder;

   String urlUsed = (String) portBP.getRequestContext().
           get(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY);
       System.out.println("Using URL: " + urlUsed);



   ((BindingProvider)myOrder).getRequestContext().put(
           BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, CORRECT_USERNAME);
       ((BindingProvider)myOrder).getRequestContext().put(
           BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, CORRECT_PASSWORD);



       AliveRequest aliveRequest = new AliveRequest();

       MerchantInfo merchInfo = new MerchantInfo();

       merchInfo.setMerchantId(CORRECT_MERCHANT_ID);

       aliveRequest.setMerchantInfo(merchInfo);




   AliveResponse aliveResponse = myOrder.alive(aliveRequest);

}
```

It fails with "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused" exception. When I build a request from the same WSDL using SOAPUI,  populate the same fields with same values and enter the same basic authentication credentials, a valid response is returned.

Comment: Also, if I put the same URL rendered by System.out.println("Using URL: " + urlUsed) in the browser, I can see SOAP response, so the connection works

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the fact that my Java client didn't send the request through the proxy, so my own company's firewall was blocking it. Unlike my own Java client, SOAPUI actually detects the proxy settings of the system (probably reads system environment variables) when SOAPUI's proxy settings are set "auto" (default). The solution was to set the following system properties:

```
-Dhttps.proxySet=true
-Dhttps.proxyHost=MY_PROXY_HOST
-Dhttps.proxyPort=MY_PROXY_PORT
```